# What does "small amount of ease" mean?

Tags: phrases

If you say you want something to occur with a "small amount of ease", what are you actually saying? I understand that the intention of this phrase is typically that you want something to be done easily; but, does it literally mean that something should be hard?

Answer (score 4):

It's a meaning of *ease* rather specific to sewing (or clothing): [“space to move within your clothing”](http://www.getcreativeshow.com/seminars/sewing_ease.htm). So, “a small amount of ease” is synonymous with “a little leeway”, “a margin of safety”. It does not mean “effortless”.

Google Books provides [some real-world hits](http://books.google.com/books?id=cEHda-hgcHMC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=%22small%20amount%20of%20ease%22&source=bl&ots=8KP_5o_h0S&sig=IuAoVg5QByfJYBvt-AqBjLMTK7k&hl=en&ei=yIWwTdOiLIi6hAfZycCOBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22small%20amount%20of%20ease%22&f=false) of literal use of this expression, though it appears to be used figuratively in your case.

Comment: It's also used in real estate, but normally as easement rather than just ease

Answer (score 1):

No native English speaker would ever use *small amount of ease* to mean *effortless*. The only context I could imagine it being appropriately used is if you were applying *ease* to something with the intent of loosening or lessening pressure, e.g., altering a garment or fitting a pipe.

Comment: It's not about being effortless, I believe it's a sewing-specific meaning of “ease”.

Comment: @F'x So you are agreeing with me?

Comment: @HaL: I agree with you that it doesn't mean "effortless". But I don't agree that it is “improper”, it simply has a different meaning.

Comment: @F'x Why is "improper" in quotes? I didn't use that word (or suggest that meaning) in my answer.

Comment: @HaL: I mean “improper” as having the meaning contrary to “being appropriately used” (which you said). I think it can be appropriately used to mean “with a margin of safety” (see my answer).

Comment: @F'x Ah, I see.

Answer (score -1):

You can say

- with ease
- with little difficulty
- with only a small amount of effort

Or you can incorrectly muddle up these idioms and come up with a construction that doesn't make sense, taken literally, but whose meaning you can guess at.